# Registering fonts from classpath throws java.nio.BufferUnderflowException

Tags: java, fonts, jar

Basically, what I'm trying to do is register all fonts(.ttf) in a directory in the classpath. Doing this while running as a jar file is more complicated compared to doing it when the application is launched from the IDE. When I launch the app from my IDE, no exceptions are thrown and I can use the fonts right away. However, when I launch the app through the jar file, it still registers the font but it throws this exception:

```
java.awt.FontFormatException: java.nio.BufferUnderflowException
at sun.font.TrueTypeFont.init(Unknown Source)
at sun.font.TrueTypeFont.<init>(Unknown Source)
at sun.font.TrueTypeFont.<init>(Unknown Source)
at sun.font.SunFontManager.createFont2D(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Font.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Font.createFont0(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Font.createFont(Unknown Source)
at com.cyr1en.cgdl.util.FontUtil.lambda$registerAllFonts$1(FontUtil.java:65)
at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(Unknown Source)
at com.cyr1en.cgdl.util.FontUtil.registerAllFonts(FontUtil.java:63)
at com.cyr1en.test.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:20)
```

But as I said, the fonts still registered and I was still able to use it.

Here's my registration function:

```
public static void registerAllFonts(String fontsDir) {
    try {
        GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        final File jarFile = new File(FontUtil.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI().getPath());
        if (FileUtil.isJarFile(jarFile)) {
            JarFile jar = new JarFile(jarFile);
            Enumeration<JarEntry> entries = jar.entries();
            ArrayList<JarEntry> jarEntries = Collections.list(entries);
            List<JarEntry> fonts = jarEntries.stream().filter(f -> f.getName().startsWith(fontsDir)).collect(Collectors.toList());
            fonts.forEach(f -> {
                try {
                    ge.registerFont(Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, jar.getInputStream(f)));
                } catch (FontFormatException | IOException e) {
                    ExceptionUtil.generateErrorLog(e);
                }
            });
            jar.close();
        } else {
            URL url = FontUtil.class.getResource(fontsDir);
            if (url != null) {
                File file = new File(url.toURI());
                if (file.listFiles() != null)
                    for (File f : file.listFiles()) {
                        ge.registerFont(Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, f));
                    }
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException | FontFormatException | URISyntaxException e) {
        ExceptionUtil.generateErrorLog(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Which font file is it trying to register when the error occurs?

Comment: Ohhhhhh, got it. My predicate in the filter is `f.getName().startsWith(fontsDir)` and that includes the actual font directory itself. So in my list I end up having [`fonts/`,`fonts/font1.ttf`, `fonts/font2.ttf`] and that's why it's throwing that exception. I feel stupid for this.

Comment: You should post that as an answer and then accept it 2 days later - that will register the question as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My predicate in filter() includes the actual font directory itself. So in the list, I get [`fonts/`,`fonts/font1.ttf`, `fonts/font2.ttf`], and of course you can't create a font from `fonts/`.

So the solution is to edit the predicate to:

```
.filter(f -> f.getName().startsWith(finalFontsDir) && !f.getName().equals(finalFontsDir))
```

Thanks to [@Robin Green](https://stackoverflow.com/users/495796/robin-green)

**Edit:**

Also changed the function a bit since passing `"fonts/"` as the directory won't really work for `class.getResource(fontsDir)` and will only work for `JarEntry#getName()`. So just pass `"/fonts/"` and when launched with jar, just remove the first `/`.

```
 public static void registerAllFonts(String fontsDir) {
    try {
        GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        final File jarFile = new File(FontUtil.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI().getPath());
        if (FileUtil.isJarFile(jarFile)) {
            if(fontsDir.startsWith("/"))
                fontsDir = fontsDir.substring(1);
            JarFile jar = new JarFile(jarFile);
            Enumeration<JarEntry> entries = jar.entries();
            ArrayList<JarEntry> jarEntries = Collections.list(entries);
            final String finalFontsDir = fontsDir;
            List<JarEntry> fonts = jarEntries.stream()
                    .filter(f -> f.getName().startsWith(finalFontsDir) && 
                            !f.getName().equals(finalFontsDir))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
            fonts.forEach(f -> {
                try {
                    ge.registerFont(Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, jar.getInputStream(f)));
                } catch (FontFormatException | IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
            jar.close();
        } else {
            URL url = FontUtil.class.getResource(fontsDir);
            if (url != null) {
                File file = new File(url.toURI());
                if (file.listFiles() != null)
                    for (File f : file.listFiles()) {
                        ge.registerFont(Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, f));
                    }
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException | FontFormatException | URISyntaxException e) {
        ExceptionUtil.generateErrorLog(e);
    }
}
```